# How to get a list of all the different values within a variable

Tags: r, data.table

I've always wondered if there's a command in R that gives you the entire domain of values within a variable.

For example, let's say I have the following data.table:

```
dt
Household Number_of_children
1         0
2         3
3         3
```

Is there a command along the lines of `summary()` or `str()` that would return the list `0, 3`?

I believe `summary` and `str` only do that when your variable is a character string. I don't know how to do this when your variable is an integer, numeric, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to get unique values of a variable? Try unique(dt$Number_of_children)

Comment: List is a special data structure in R. So you should be bit careful about names of data-structures in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unique() function, with column/vector as input.

```
unique(dt[,'Number_of_children'])
```

Comment: This is exactly the function I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also often useful is to replace `unique` here with `table` to show the number of occurrences of each unique value.